# Modulo Infrarrojo Arduino no funciona

Tags: arduino

tengo un modulo YS-IRTM v3, aqui esta la imagen para que lo puedan ver,

https://www.microjpm.com/products/ad32706/

He programado para utilizar el receptor, declaro alguno de los pines Digitales y todo funciona a la perfección.
Pero a la hora de programar para enviar los codigos al TV, no me funciona, la prueba lo hice con un LED infrarrojo normal y si me funciona, pero con el módulo no logro que funciona, este es el programa.

```
 #include <IRLib.h>

IRsend My_Sender;

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

My_Sender.send(SONY,0xa8bca, 20);

}
```

Este fragmento de código es muy pequeño, se que si logro hacerlo con este pequeño código ya tendría una base para hacerlo mas elaborado.
Otra cosa es que si ven no estan declarado los pines solo esta el My_Sender, a cual de los pines debería conectar el módulo?

Gracias por cualquier comentario de ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este modulo se comunica por comunicación serial, debería ir conectado así:

```
Arduino     Modulo  
5V      ->  5V
RX      ->  TX  
TX      ->  RX
GND     ->  GND
```

No utiliza la librería IRLib esta es para controlar un led infrarojo.
Este es un ejemplo que encontre en https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=359707.0

```
int byte_entrante = 0;//Para datos seriales entrantes

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);//abre el puerto serie, establece la velocidad de datos a 9600 bps
}

void loop() {

    //Envia datos solo cuando recive datos
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        //Lee el byte entrante
        byte_entrante = Serial.read();

        //Di lo que tienes
        Serial.print("Recibí: ");
        Serial.println(byte_entrante, HEX);
    }
}
```

Si tienes el arduino uno no puedes estar conectado al computador y al modulo a la vez porque usarían la misma conexión serial.